Oracle 19c Query to get difference between request and response
I have a single table where request and response are logged as 2 separate rows. I am trying to write an oracle query to

find the time difference between REQUEST and RESPONSE records
get the record count processing in 1 sec, 2 sec, 3 sec, 4 sec...

Table A



ID
TRAN_ID
Stage
Timestamp




1
AAA
REQUEST
09-JAN-24 07.47.07.489000000 AM


2
AAA
RESPONSE
09-JAN-24 07.47.07.689000000 AM


3
BBB
REQUEST
09-JAN-24 07.47.07.489000000 AM


4
BBB
RESPONSE
09-JAN-24 07.47.09.489000000 AM



OUTPUT
1.
| TRANID | Seconds |
| AAA    | 0       |
| BBB    | 2       |


2. 
| Seconds |  count |
| 0       |     1  |
| 2       |     1  |

I tried the following query
select RES.timestamp - REQ.timestamp diff
from A
where REQ.TRAN_ID = RES.TRAN_ID;


I don't understand the output. Why doesn't Tran_ID BBB have an output for question 1? And what are you trying to show as your output for question 2? The editing is odd and no idea what you really want for Question 2 output.

Assuming each tran_id only has one request and one response (or you want the span across all of them) then you can use conditional aggregation twice to get the two timestamps:
select tran_id,
  min(case when stage = 'REQUEST' then timestamp end) as request,
  max(case when stage = 'RESPONSE' then timestamp end) as response
from a
group by tran_id




TRAN_ID
REQUEST
RESPONSE




AAA
09-JAN-24 07.47.07.489000000
09-JAN-24 07.47.07.689000000


BBB
09-JAN-24 07.47.07.489000000
09-JAN-24 07.47.09.489000000



then subtract them, which gives you an interval:
select tran_id,
  max(case when stage = 'RESPONSE' then timestamp end)
    - min(case when stage = 'REQUEST' then timestamp end) as diff
from a
group by tran_id




TRAN_ID
DIFF




AAA
+000000000 00:00:00.200000000


BBB
+000000000 00:00:02.000000000



and get the seconds part of that, either floored or rounded to an integer:
select tran_id,
  floor(extract(second from max(case when stage = 'RESPONSE' then timestamp end)
    - min(case when stage = 'REQUEST' then timestamp end))) as seconds
from a
group by tran_id




TRAN_ID
SECONDS




AAA
0


BBB
2



And then use that as a subquery to aggregate against:
select seconds, count(*)
from (
  select floor(extract(second from max(case when stage = 'RESPONSE' then timestamp end)
    - min(case when stage = 'REQUEST' then timestamp end))) as seconds
  from a
  group by tran_id
)
group by seconds
order by seconds




SECONDS
COUNT(*)




0
1


2
1



fiddle
I've also assume the response and request will be close together... if that can actually ever take more than a minute then you will need to extract and include the minute (and maybe hour, and day...) part of the interval difference to get the total number of seconds.

@user7754677 Please consider marking the Accept Answer flag if this resolves your question.
